# Will deleting my microsoft account from my laptop lock me out of my laptop?

Tags: windows-8

I set up my new Win 8.1 laptop today and, I guess because I didn't skip the connect to a network option, I ended up being forced to enter my email and password. I did that and now my email address is on the screen and I have to enter my password before I can log in and use my laptop. I've found two articles on getting rid of this:

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3494536/remove-microsoft-account-from-windows-8/

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-change-to-a-local-account-in-windows-81/

And I'm grateful. My question is this: If I delete the account off my laptop will my actual email account be deleted too?

Second question: If the above is not true, after making a local account can I delete my current account from my laptop just so it's completely gone?

Comment: 1. no. 2. yes..

Answer (score 2):

If you delete a account from your Windows 8.1 Laptop, your email won't be deleted.

If you have more than one account you can always delete accounts. But you can delete the account only if you have administrator privileges. So you have to do this:

Lets assume you have only one account on your laptop. Create new **Administrator** account, name it SuperUser, now sign in to SuperUser and delete the account yo wish to delete. Create one more Account but with standard user privileges and use it as your default account. You should never use a Administrator Account as your default account out of security reasons.